# JS code into PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I can not add JS code into PHP code

JavaScript File:

```
 $.each(data.data,function(i,modul){
 tb.append("<p><?php if (!is_dir($rootPath . '/Includes/'" + value.id+ "'")) { ?> <span>Test</span><?php } else { ?> <span>Test</span><?php } ?></p>"});
```

This line:

```
 ' + value.id+ ' = This is a JS code
```

Where do I make mistakes?
Thanks

Comment: That's not how php/javascript work...

Comment: A good IDE will point out that you have a huge syntax error with mismatched quotes. Also, PHP runs before the page is sent to the browser, javascript after. You can't manipulate PHP variables in javascript.

Comment: I use PHPstorm but syntax is normal @aynber